# Lubuntu 13.10 Minimal Install shows no desktop

Tags: lubuntu, ubuntu-minimal

I installed the "Lubuntu Minimal Desktop" via the 13.10 mini.iso CD image. That means, I should get the basic Lubuntu Desktop without all the programs.

After the installation is finished the system reboots and I am presented with the (graphical, not command line) login screen. However, after I enter the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens. The Login box disappears, the wallpaper stays the same, and I get no desktop.

I can still move the mouse around and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to log into the console.

I tried both the 32 bit and 64 bit CD images, as well as installing them on real hardware and in a VM. Every time with the same result.

I followed [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall).

Is the "Lubuntu Minimal Desktop" option broken?

Comment: I used Lubuntu instead from the menu and it still worked, gave me adesktop the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this issue as well.  Here's how I got around it.

At the login screen, select Openbox and login.  You will still have no desktop.  Right-click on the background and open up a terminal emulator window.  Execute the following:

sudo apt-get install lxde

After this, I was able to switch back to the LXDE interface and get in with a desktop one would expect to have on login.

Comment: Thank you! I never even suspected that this could be the problem. "LX Games" is selected by default instead of "Lubuntu" at the Login screen. If I choose the right one, it works (duh). Thanks!